# check if the temporary file(semaphore) exists using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, temp

how can I read(check) a temp file created on my system please.

I need to check if a temp file exists or not using scala,

how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val path = new Path("/tmp/foo/bar/meow.parquet")
if (fileSystem.exists(path)){
    // TODO ...
}
```

It will work on local, Docker and remote file-systems (S3 & HDFS) fluently

Hope it helps